# What is the difference when connecting through a proxy?

Tags: proxy

I know what a proxy is, and the basics of how they work.

What I was wondering is, what is different in a request that goes through a proxy?

I know when I configure Firefox I simply configure the proxy in a dialog.  When I program in python I can use an environment variable.

If I am programming in an environment that doesn't already have support for a proxy, how do I connect through a proxy?  Is there an extra header added to requests?  Is the protocol slightly different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol is slightly different.  Where a direct connection to `example.com` would say:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

a connection through a proxy would say:

```
GET http://example.com/index.html HTTP/1.1
```